# Sharepoint 2013 Restrict user to access _layout pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have created site in SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013. I want to restrict login user to access _layouts pages like view all site content etc.. In SharePoint 2010 I have activated view form pages lock down feature by below command

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -url <site collection url> -filename ViewFormPagesLockDown\feature.xml
```

after that i have re enable anonymous access and i have give restricted read permission to sharepoint group. And it is working. Same step i have follow in Sharepoint 2013 site. But their is not restricted read permission their. So i am not able to restrict user.

What to do for Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/preventing-authenticated-visitors-browsing-system-pages/) blog helped me in SP2010. I can't imagine these settings has been changed too much from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Hi Daniel , Thank you for your answer. Its works for both Sharepoint 2013 and Sharepoint 2010